# How to visit Lake Hillier?

Tags: australia, lakes

Is it possible to visit [Lake Hillier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Hillier)?

Do I have to go with tour or can I for example rent a car and go there? I see no roads near it.

[image: Aerial view of Lake Hillier]

Comment: As an alternative, there's another pink lake nearby, mysteriously named ["Pink Lake"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Lake_(Western_Australia)) which has a tourist park so is easily visitable. Though the pictures do not look as spectacular as the ones of Lake Hillier.

Comment: @HaLaBi What makes it pink ?

Comment: Surprising for a national landmark there isn't any readily available information of how to get to/from there...

Comment: Yum. I can't answer that? But I can answer how it's pink. I have a bottle of cyanobacteria, and it forms into a pink color. Algae lightens the shade.

Comment: @hippietrail "Pink Lake" isn't a good alternative, as it hasn't been pink since 2007, due to changes in water flow ([link](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-07-31/scientists-say-they-can-make-pink-lake-pink-again/11352068) to news article).

Comment: @ascha: Bummer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try contacting [Esperance Tourism](http://www.westernaustralia.com/en/Attraction/Archipelago_of_the_Recherche/9009391), and asking them the best way to see this specific island (Middle Island, in the Archipelago of the Recherche).

It's on an island off the coast so driving is not an option. I would imagine there would be a ferry, as (from the link) they are promoting the Archipelago as a tourist destination.

Esperance is a long way from both Perth and Adelaide (the two closest capitals), so I would recommend you line up some other things to do down there too.

Answer (score 5):

Lake Hillier is on an island the only way to get there is via helicopter (Esperance Helitours) which is a 2 hour return flight from Esperance townsite

Comment: Could you add some more detail? Have you done the trip yourself? Any links?